# Rate-Limit - TCP Server (net.Server)

Tags: node.js, typescript, tcp, rate-limiting, ddos

I am using [net.Server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html) as my TCP server.

How can I enforce message rate limit?

I found similar solution for Express ([express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit)) and Websocket ([websocket-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws-rate-limit)) but not for TCP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rate-limiter-flexible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rate-limiter-flexible) package can be used for that.

It supports many stores like Redis, MongoDB, etc. Here is the most simple example with in memory storage:

```js
const opts = {
  points: 10, // 10 points
  duration: 1, // Per second
};

const rateLimiter = new RateLimiterMemory(opts);

rateLimiter.consume(remoteAddress, 1) // consume 1 point
    .then((rateLimiterRes) => {
      // 1 point consumed
      // Some app logic here
    })
    .catch((rateLimiterRes) => {
      // Not enough points to consume
    });
```

[More examples on Wiki](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki)

Comment: Thanks!
I came across it too. 
I was surprised it was published recently: it made me wonder how come there's no existing TCP-dedicated solution already [and that I must be missing something].
All and all - I found it quite easy to use!
Providing also this paper for whoever find this question (it was interesting for me to read).
https://medium.com/@animirr/rate-limiting-brute-force-and-ddos-attacks-protection-in-node-js-2492c4a9249